# Adding ProjectionMatrix to entity results in wierd behavior when rendering

Tags: java, glsl, rendering, lwjgl, projection-matrix

## Introduction to the problem:

I'm working on a game engine using the LWJGL library following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50Y9u7K0PZo). However, I'm trying to make it so that there is a real division between the main engine and the game itself. I've therefore complicated the project a whole lot and I think this is causing some problems as the ProjectionMatrix doesn't work as explained in the video.

## What am I doing:

**Creating the ProjectionMatrix:**

In order to create a ProjectionMatrix I created the a method which creates it for me:

```
public static Matrix4f createProjectionMatrix(float aspectRatio, float fov, float nearPlane, float farPlane) {
    float y_scale = (float) ((1f / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fov / 2f))) * aspectRatio);
    float x_scale = y_scale / aspectRatio;
    float frustum_length = nearPlane - farPlane;

    Matrix4f projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    projectionMatrix.m00 = x_scale;
    projectionMatrix.m11 = y_scale;
    projectionMatrix.m22 = -((farPlane + nearPlane) / frustum_length);
    projectionMatrix.m23 = -1;
    projectionMatrix.m32 = -((2 * nearPlane * farPlane) / frustum_length);
    projectionMatrix.m33 = 0;

    return projectionMatrix;
}
```

I create the ProjectionMatrix with the following values:

```
aspectRatio = width/height = 640/480 = 1.33333
fov = 100
nearPlane = -0.5
farPlane = 100
```

This results in the following values for my ProjectionMatrix:

```
0.83909965  0.0         0.0        0.0
0.0         0.83909965  0.0        0.0
0.0         0.0         0.9990005  -0.9995003
0.0         0.0        -1.0        0.0
```

**Using the ProjectionMatrix:**

In order to use the ProjectionMatrix I created the following shaders:

*vertex.vs:*

```
#version 150

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoordinates;

out vec2 passTextureCoordinates;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform int useProjectionMatrix;

void main(void){
    if (useProjectionMatrix == 1) {
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    } else {
        gl_Position = transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    }
    passTextureCoordinates = textureCoordinates;

}
```

*fragment.fs:*

```
#version 150

in vec2 passTextureCoordinates;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

void main(void){

    out_Color = texture(textureSampler,passTextureCoordinates);

}
```

Finally in order to render the entity I've created the following renderer class:

```
public class TexturedEntityRenderer extends AbstractEntityRenderer{

    private float aspectRatio;
    private float fov;
    private float nearPlane;
    private float farPlane;

    public void prepare() {
        GL11.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void render (AbstractEntity entity, AbstractShader shader) {
        if(shader instanceof TexturedEntityShader) {
            if(entity.getModel() instanceof TexturedModel) {
                TexturedModel model = (TexturedModel)entity.getModel();
                GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVaoID());
                GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
                GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
                Matrix4f transformationMatrix = MatrixMaths.createTransformationMatrix(entity.getPosition(), entity.getRx(), entity.getRy(), entity.getRz(), entity.getScale());
                ((TexturedEntityShader)shader).loadTransformationMatrix(transformationMatrix);
                GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
                GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, ((TexturedModel)entity.getModel()).getTexture().getTextureID());
                GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.getVaoID());
                GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
                GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
                GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
                GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
            } else {
                ExceptionThrower.throwException(new ModelInvalidException());
            }
        } else {
            ExceptionThrower.throwException(new ShaderIncompatableException(shader.toString()));
        }
    }

    public void setup(AbstractShader shader) {
        nearPlane = Float.parseFloat(OptionHandler.getProperty(GraphicOptions.WINDOWNEARPLANE_KEY, OptionHandler.GRAPHIC_OPTION_ID));
        farPlane = Float.parseFloat(OptionHandler.getProperty(GraphicOptions.WINDOWFARPLANE_KEY, OptionHandler.GRAPHIC_OPTION_ID));
        aspectRatio = DisplayManager.getWidth() / DisplayManager.getHeight();
        fov = Float.parseFloat(OptionHandler.getProperty(GraphicOptions.WINDOWFOV_KEY, OptionHandler.GRAPHIC_OPTION_ID));
        ((TexturedEntityShader)shader).loadProjectionMatrix(MatrixMaths.createProjectionMatrix(aspectRatio, fov, nearPlane, farPlane));
        ((TexturedEntityShader)shader).loadUseProjectionMatrix();
    }
}
```

The `Optionhandler.getProperty()` function in the `setup()` returns the property for a given key(like fov or nearPlane value) from a text file. (I've checked that this works by printing all loaded options.) Also, the `DisplayManager.getWidth()` and `DisplayManager.getHeight()` functions, obviously, obtain the width and height for calculating the aspectRatio variable.

**Updating the entity:**

Last but not least, I'm updating the entity using a class called EntityModifier which looks like this:

```
public class EntityModifier {

    private Vector3f dposition;
    private float drx;
    private float dry;
    private float drz;
    private float dscale;

    public BasicEntityModifier(Vector3f dposition, float drx, float dry, float drz, float dscale) {
        this.dposition = dposition;
        this.drx = drx;
        this.dry = dry;
        this.drz = drx;
        this.dscale = dscale;
    }

    public Vector3f getDposition() {
        return dposition;
    }

    public float getDrx() {
        return drx;
    }

    public float getDry() {
        return dry;
    }

    public float getDrz() {
        return drz;
    }

    public float getDscale() {
        return dscale;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BasicEntityModifier [dposition=" + dposition + ", drx=" + drx + ", dry=" + dry + ", drz=" + drz + ", dscale=" + dscale + "]";
    }

}
```

Each entity I create has one of these classes and I cal call an update method which adds the values to the entity's transformation:

```
public void update() {
        increasePosition(modifier.getDposition().getX(),modifier.getDposition().getY(),modifier.getDposition().getZ());
        increaseRotation(modifier.getDrx(), modifier.getDry(), modifier.getDrz());
        increaseScale(modifier.getDscale());
    }

    private void increasePosition(float dx, float dy, float dz) {
        position.x += dx;
        position.y += dy;
        position.z += dz;

    }

    private void increaseRotation(float drx, float dry, float drz) {
        rx += drx;
        ry += dry;
        rz += drz;
    }

    private void increaseScale(float dscale) {
        scale += dscale;
    }
```

## The problem:

I'm able to change the position of the `x` and `y` values of the entity normally but whenever I change the `z` position, using an EntityModifier, the entity loads but then dissapears from the screen. It's loaded for about 60 frames before dissapearing and changing `dz`'s value doesn't seem to affect the speed at which it dissapears in any way(It does, see EDIT 2). Also there the entity doesn't have the scale effect as shown in the [tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50Y9u7K0PZo&t=707s) (same link but with timestamp).

Changing the `dz` value to 0 stops the dissapearing of the entity.

What is going on here? How can I fix this?

## EDIT:

I've been pointed out in the comments that the nearPlane value should be positive so I changed it to 0.5 but I still get the same results. I also changed: `float frustum_length = nearPlane - farPlane;` to `float frustum_length = farPlane - nearPlane;` which was also suggested there (this also did not solve the problem).

## EDIT 2:

After some more investigation I found a few intresting things:

**1.** Changing the speed at which the z value changes does affect how long it takes for the entity to dissapear. After finding this out I tried timing a few different dz(with dz being the change per frame of z) values and I got this:

```
`for dz = -0.002 -> frames before dissapear: 515 frames.`
`for dz = -0.001 -> frames before dissapear: 1024 frames.`
`for dz = 0.02   -> frames before dissapear: 63 frames.`
```

If we take into account reaction times (I made the program output the total ammount of rendered frames on closure and just closed it as fast as possible when the entity dissapeared) we can calculate the values for z at which the entity dissapears.

```
-0.002 * 515  ≈ -1
-0.001 * 1024 ≈ -1
 0.02  * 63   ≈  1
```

This probably has to do with the way the coordinate system works in OpenGL but it still doesn't explain why the entity isn't becoming smaller as it does in the tutorial mentioned above.

**2.** Removing the code which adds the ProjectionMatrix to the renderer class does not change the behavior. This means the error is elsewere.

**New Problem:**

I think there is no problem with the ProjectionMatrix (or at least not a problem that is causing this behavior) but the problem is with the entity's position surpassing 1 or -1 on the z axes. However this still doesn't explain why there is no "zoom effect". Therefor I don't think that restricting the z movement between -1 and 1 will solve this problem, infact, I think it will work against us as the entity should not be rendered anyway if it's totaly "zoomed" out or in.

What can cause this problem if it isn't the ProjectionManager?

## EDIT 3:

Someone on reddit pointed out that the following classes might also be of intrest for solving the problem:

[AbstractShader](https://pastebin.com/cRzLYYJh): contains basic shader functionality common for all shader classes.

[TexturedEntityShader](https://pastebin.com/Hv1xWsFc): used to render a texturedEntity (shown above)

[DisplayManager](https://pastebin.com/A6NzYX0y): class which handles rendering.

## EDIT 4:

After some more discussion on reddit about this problem we've come across a problem and were able to fix it: The value for `useProjectionMatrix` was not loaded because the shader was stopped when I tried to load it. Changing the `loadUseProjectionMatrix()` method to:

```
public void loadUseProjectionMatrix() {
    super.start();
    super.loadBoolean(useProjectionMatrixLocation, useProjectionMatrix);
    System.out.println("loaded useProjectionMatrix: " + useProjectionMatrix + "\n\n");
    super.stop();
}
```

seems to partially solve the problem as the projectionMatrix now can be used inside the shader (before it would not be used due to the fact that the `useProjectionMatrix` value would always be `0` as we did not load a value for it.).

However, this did not fix the entire problem as there is still an issue with the projectionMatrix I think. The entity does not want to render at all when using the projectionMatrix but it renders fine when not using it. I've tried hardcoding the values of the projectionMatrix by using the following shader:

```
#version 150

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoordinates;

out vec2 passTextureCoordinates;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform int useProjectionMatrix;

mat4 testMat;

void main(void){

    testMat[0] = vec4(0.83909965, 0, 0, 0);
    testMat[1] = vec4(0, 0.83909965, 0, 0);
    testMat[2] = vec4(0, 0, 0.9990005,  -0.9995003);
    testMat[3] = vec4(0, 0, -1,  0);

    if (true) {
        gl_Position = testMat * transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    } else {
        gl_Position = transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    }
    passTextureCoordinates = textureCoordinates;

}
```

However that does not seem to work. Are these values OK?

Fow who wants to see it here are the 2 posts I created on reddit about this problem: [post 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/9p6yh3/problem_with_a_rendering_engine_im_creating/), [post 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/9p7k2p/problem_with_a_rendering_engine_im_creating_in/).

Comment: Your perspective projection matrix is wrong. Both the near plane and the far plane have to be positive values: `nearPlane = 0.5`, `farPlane = 100`. Note a frustum is a truncated pyramid, the near plane cuts the top and the far plane limits the size. The frustum length is the positive distance between the far plane and the near plane: `frustum_length = farPlane - nearPlane;`

Comment: @Rabbid76 I've changed the nearPlane value to 0.5 but I still get the same results

Comment: And what bout `frustum_length = farPlane - nearPlane` - instead of `frustum_length = nearPlane - farPlane` as I mentioned in the comment above?

Comment: Nope still the same results.

Comment: Further: `float t = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fov / 2f))`; `float x_scale = (float)(1f / (t*aspectRatio));` `float y_scale = (float)(1f / t);`

Comment: I've made an edit with some important information. maybe you could take a look at it. Also it seems that the calculation you're doing in your last comment does the same thing as what I allready have (if my maths don't fail me here...)